Macbook M2 2022 Keyboard Not Functioning Well
Some keys on my keyboard is unresponsive, when I hold it for more than 2 secs, it does type a letter. The keys are 'l', 'o','9','.', '-', and the right arrow. The whole keys except those keys are working normally.
I have make sure slow & stick keys were disabled. I also booted the laptop in safe mode, but still got that behaviour. Please suggest me what to do with the issue. Thank you.

Keyboard problems that affect a group of keys in the same region, particularly in a vertical line, suggest a hardware fault.
You should take the Mac to an Apple Store or other Apple authorised repair shop.
